# R/arrow summarizing on variable columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, apache-arrow

I have a large-ish parquet file I'm referencing via `arrow::open_dataset`. I'd like to get the max value of *one or more* of the columns, where I don't know a priori which (or how many) columns. In general, this sounds like "programming with dplyr" (assuming arrow-10 and its recent support of `dplyr::across`), but I can't get it to work.

```r
write_parquet(data.frame(a=c(1,9), b=c(2,10), d=c("q","r")), "quux.parquet")
vars <- c("a")
open_dataset("quux.parquet") %>%
  summarize(across(sym(vars), ~ max(.))) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#       a
#   <dbl>
# 1     9
```

But when `vars` is length 2 or more, I assume I need to be using `syms` or similar, but that fails with

```r
vars <- c("a", "b")
open_dataset("quux.parquet") %>%
  summarize(across(all_of(syms(vars)), ~ max(.))) %>%
  collect()
# Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
# x Subscript has the wrong type `list`.
# i It must be numeric or character.
```

How do I lazily (not load all data) find the max of multiple columns in an arrow dataset?

While I suspect that the correct answer in dplyr will be some form of `syms`, and then whether or not arrow supports that is the next question. I'm not tied to the dplyr mechanisms, if there's a method using `ds$NewScan()` or similar, I'm amenable.

Comment: Can you say what `vars` is?  A character vector with variable names as string?

Comment: Yes, oops, copy/paste issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're after - using tidyselect's all_of function?

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

write_parquet(data.frame(a=c(1,9), b=c(2,10), d=c("q","r")), "quux.parquet")

vars <- c("a", "d")

open_dataset("quux.parquet") %>%
  summarize(across(all_of(vars), ~ max(.))) %>%
  collect()
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>       a d    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     9 r
```

See https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/index.html for the different tidyselect functions you may also want to check out.

Comment: Ugh, I thought I had checked with the lack of `sym`/`syms`, (facepalm).

Comment: Easily done, I think any of us who've spent time wrestling with tidy eval functions get tripped up when then moving back to the "simpler" stuff that became more prominent later!